# My post was unfairly edited and locked

Tags: discussion, editing, locked

My previous [post](https://superuser.com/questions/281613/what-are-the-differences-between-2-5-and-3-5-hard-disks) was getting edit and I think the edit was wrong.

Look at the Revision 2, sblair completely changed my post, which include a line here:

"I want one of my friends to buy a 1TB hard disk for me, but I have no idea about this value. I only know that 7200rpm is better (than 5400rpm)."

This is confusing because I know what does 1 TB stands for, what I am asking is the 2.5/3.5 value. So I think this edit is wrong, so I rollbacked it.

In some minutes slhck rollbacked my post to Revision 2, then I rollbacked it to the original one. Now I find out the original message is missing something which I typed(Maybe network reason). Sorry for that, and I edit it so that it is complete in Revision 6.

Than the moderator appear and rollbacked my post to Revision 2, abandoned all of my edit. I think it is unfair to abandon all of my change, all of my edit.

Comment: lock up this post if the moderator like to lock up something. Plus he locked up my post too.

Comment: This thing, that thing, the other thing. My 2.5 inch thing, my 3.5 inch thing. Seriously? If you don't want people putting their time and effort into improving your questions, then you need to put your own effort into making your questions better.

Comment: Now don't make another post complaining about this getting edited.

Comment: Yes, I now realise that I made the second paragraph ambiguous - sorry about that. The revision history shows that it was my mistake, not yours. But it's not particularly relevant to the question anyway. I did leave a friendly comment explaining that I had edited the question, and that the edited version may not be exactly what you were trying to ask. Next time, it would be better to edit the post directly rather than removing others' edits.

Comment: Sorry about that. +1

Answer (score 14):

> what I am asking is the 2.5/3.5 value. So I think this edit is wrong, so I rollbacked it.

And **that's what** is highlighted in the revision 2 of the post.

> What does the 2.5"/3.5" value indicate? The thickness?
>
> I want one of my friends to buy a 1TB hard disk for me, but I have no idea about this value. I only know that 7200rpm is better (than 5400rpm).

**Where** is your concern about

> because I know what does 1 TB stands for, what I am asking is the 2.5/3.5 value.

getting ignored? Your question was changed from

> Usually I just buy a harddisk, but
> this day I discover there is a
> difference of something 2.5" vs 3.5"
> to choose from.
>
> WHat does this 2.5 3.5 thing indicate?
> the thickness?
>
> I want one of my friend to buy a 1 tb
> harddisk for me, but I have no idea
> about this thing, I only know 7200rpm
> is better.
>
> I am afraid if the 3.5" thing is
> bigger in size, and my friend buy me
> this, and I afraid if there will be
> any chance that the hard

to

> What does the 2.5"/3.5" value
> indicate? The thickness?
>
> I want one of my friends to buy a 1TB
> hard disk for me, but I have no idea
> about this value. I only know that
> 7200rpm is better (than 5400rpm).
>
> I am worried that the 3.5" drive may
> be physically too big.

The second edit has not only resulted in a more concise question, but also one that's more readable, better grammatically and something which can be answered by reading the first sentence of the question. I don't know what you're arguing about, the rollback wars were senseless and **that's why** I locked it.

Contrary to what most people think, Mods don't have a fetish to close and lock questions. We're here to ensure everything goes on smooth and fine. And the earlier people understand **why** is it that their posts are getting edited, closed & locked upon, the better it will be for them - not only in Stack Exchange but everywhere.

Comment: "this value" in the edited sentence looks like it is referring back to the 1TB nomenclature.  It needs to be worded better, not locked in place for eternity.

Comment: The real issue is that the OP was ignored when he tried to fix it, instead of having his input considered.  I would have heavily edited his question also, but we always have to watch changing the meaning.  We always have to be ready to own up to our mistakes and fix our edits (as I've had to do a few times).

Comment: No, the real issue is that OP went about on a rollback war. The focus is on the first sentence, nothing else.

Comment: That's the problem, you focused on the first sentence, and didn't pay enough attention to the others.  Just fix it.

Comment: What's the meaning of rollback, if rollback a coupon of time makes it a war?

Comment: The editor completely change my post, I don't think that is my question, I can't even recognize it anymore.

Comment: @Saythya, "rollback war" seems a bit harsh judgement for a guy who just wanted to get his question right, to his own mind. Hell, I've personally hit rollback _twice_ on a single question's pile of edits as I realize which ones were reasonable, which ones weren't, and hoped to $DEITY I wasn't trashing someone's in-flight edit attempt to bring sanity to the whole mess.

Answer (score 10):

I think the first edit was just fine. It improved spelling, language and made the question clearer.

I would have removed even more, the bit about it being 1TB is totally irrelevant to your question and  how in the world does it matter if you or your friend buys it?

Your question would be just fine with just the following sentence.

> What is the difference between a 2.5" and a 3.5" harddisk?

Comment: That sentence would have been sufficient, but the editor changed the meaning of the 1TB sentence.

Comment: In the context of the post, the sentence does not appear confusing. "This" value is the one in the title and the first sentence.

Answer (score 6):

The mods here make good points - I too think the question was improved by the edits, stilistically, grammatically and in focus.  No problems there.

But if a user *insists* on their version, and there is nothing fundamentally broken with it (like textspeak or screwed up formatting), why deny them the right to roll it back? Let the community vote on it, and decide what it deserves. Are stylistic changes really worth fighting over? It takes two to start a rollback war.

Comment: The fact is that if you ask a question here on Super User or any Stack Exchange site the content is "yours" to own, per se.  We are asked as editors/mods/other higher rep users to make changes that are considerate of the OP's desire.  However, if changes weren't made, more than likely it would've been voted to close as it was very difficult to understand what was going on.

Comment: I just think there's a difference between asking to keep a version and insisting on it by saying something like "Don't you dare to edit my question!", which is just not the principle of SO imo.

Answer (score -6):

You're right, some of the edits were inappropriate and shouldn't have been made the way they were.  The moderator then locked in a bad edit.  I've flagged it, but in reality it'll just cost me flag points.  I hope you like the answers given even if the question ended up wrong.

EDIT: verified, I just lost 10 flag points immediately, so the mods didn't even bother to think about the situation.  Too bad we can't grade the mods.

Comment: Related Post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90677/let-the-community-grade-the-mods

Comment: "I just lost 10 flag points immediately, so the mods didn't even bother to think about the situation." -- How does that follow at all?

Comment: @mmyers, because they didn't take the time to do a full evaluation, which would require looking at the edit revisions (as I did).

Comment: And how do you know that? It takes maybe 30 seconds to see what happened there, especially if you saw it the first time around.

Comment: @mmyers, I'm not claiming omniscience, just using logical deductions.  They're welcome to give the actual point-by-point details if they wish.

Comment: You deducted logically that the same mod who locked the post also acted upon your flag without any knowledge whatsoever? That's... very logical.

Comment: @Sathya, yes it is on Super User where there are few mods, you're welcome to chime in if it was otherwise.  Also note that I didn't use the word 'whatsoever'.

Comment: I won't quote your flag message here, but you completely missed the purpose and effect of the edits that were "locked in". You'd do well to re-read the revision history, or at least Sathya's answer.

Comment: @Lance Few mods? Diago, Troggy, Random, Ivo, Sathya, Studiohack, DMA and nhinkle. Guess my count must be off...

Comment: @ivo: Gnoupi and how-to-geek?

Comment: Those are on a metaphoric moderating 'break', so to say @Kyle

Comment: @ivo gotcha, just didn't want them to feel like they were left out :P

Comment: @Kyle: ~quack? -

Comment: @Hello71, ~quack was replaced by nhinkle :-)